# Navigation transition

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am new to jQuery and am teaching myself as I go but am struggling to figure out how to indicate that on up scroll the white navigation background moves up to show the white navigation text on panel 1?

bartaile.com is what I am using as inspiration & the changes I'm making to bartaile's navigation are---> after the user scrolls past the first panel the navigation hides, only when the user scrolls up does the navigation show again, when panel 1 comes back down the white navigation backgrouns slide up to hide and shows white text.

Any help or tips to learn how to do this would be greatly appreciated! :-)

```js
var lastScrollTop = 0;
$(window).on('scroll', function() {
    var header = $('.header');
    var stage0 = $('.stage-0');
    var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();
    if (scrollTop > lastScrollTop) {
        // down scroll
        if (scrollTop > stage0.offset().top + stage0.height()) {
            header.addClass('hide');
        }
    } else {
        // up scroll
        if (scrollTop <= stage0.offset().top + stage0.height()) {
            header.removeClass('headerBGchange headerLIchange');
   
        } else {
            header.removeClass('hide').addClass('headerBGchange headerLIchange BGupTranistion');
        }
    }
    lastScrollTop = scrollTop;
});
```

```css
.header {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-box-align: center;
    -webkit-align-items: center;
    -ms-flex-align: center;
    align-items: center;
    height: 80px;
    -webkit-transition: top .5s ease;
    transition: top .5s ease;
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    top: 0;
    background-color: transparent;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.header ul {
    margin: 20px;
    padding: 0;
}

.header ul li {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: 20px;
    color: white;
}

.header ul li:last-child {
    margin-right: 0;
}

.hide {
    top: -80px;
}

.headerBGchange {
    Background: white;
}

.BGupTranistion {
}

.header.headerLIchange ul li {
    color: Blue;
}

.header.headerLIchange {
 border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}'

 


</style>
<!--stage style--><style>

.stage {
    color: #fff;
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-box-pack: center;
    -webkit-justify-content: center;
    -ms-flex-pack: center;
    justify-content: center;
    -webkit-box-align: center;
    -webkit-align-items: center;
    -ms-flex-align: center;
    align-items: center;
    height: 100vh;
    background-color: white;
 border-bottom: 1px solid black;
    font-size: 48px;
 height: 200px;
 width: 100%;
 
}

.stage-0 {
    background: grey;
}

.stage-24 {
    background: #433937;
}
```

```html
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="header">
  <ul>
    <li>Home</li>
    <li>About</li>
    <li>Contact</li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div class="stage stage-0">1</div>
<div class="stage stage-2">3</div>
<div class="stage stage-4">5</div>
<div class="stage stage-6">7</div>
<div class="stage stage-8">9</div>
<div class="stage stage-10">11</div>
<div class="stage stage-12">13</div>
<div class="stage stage-14">15</div>
<div class="stage stage-16">17</div>
<div class="stage stage-18">19</div>
<div class="stage stage-20">21</div>
<div class="stage stage-22">23</div>
```

Comment: Instead of using `.addClass` and `.removeClass` you could be using the jQuery `.slideDown` and `.slideUp` methods.

Comment: @Sam The nav bar has other transition elements other than just sliding (background color change, and text color change)...

Comment: What is it that you need it to do, what kind of indication? Feedback to the user?

Comment: On up scroll as the bottom of div stage-0 comes back to the top of the screen I want the white background in the navigation to slide up rather then just drop off and disappear to show the white text in the navigation that shows up only in stage-0

Comment: @Dee, this is kind of irrelevant to your question, but I would recommend learning from w3schools. That's literally where everyone else came from. ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You will need to add another container to achieve the effect you're looking for. What you essentially want to have is a container at the top and another container which will fade in and out depending on your scroll behaviour. So how do you achieve that? Create a -Element on top of the page, like your gray box is there at the moment. When scrolling down, do not transform it, instead, fade in another previously hidden container to act as your navigation when not at the top of the page. Now if you scroll back up, check the scroll location, and if the two locations of both containers overlap, start fading out the container you use when not at the top of the page. I do not think there is another solution. I might try and write a codepen on it now, I will edit my post if I had success. You could also try working it out with another div inside the actual header and z-index, though that might turn out really bad.
I have done my best to achieve what you want. Here is the [CodePen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/EPmPEQ).
I used two different divs, one called .dynamic-header and one normal header, and I've added a function to detect jQuery In-Viewport.

```
$.fn.isOnScreen = function(){
    var element = this.get(0);
    var bounds = element.getBoundingClientRect();
    return bounds.top < window.innerHeight && bounds.bottom > 0;
}
```

I hope this fits your needs. Also, I changed some CSS around, using the Top-Property for the transition. You can outsource all of that into CSS classes and use them instead, but I thought this was the simplest solution for demonstration purposes. Is this what you want?

**Edit 1**: You named bartaile.com as an example. I took a look at the effect they create and recreated it. What you have to do is basically create a structure like this:

```
<div class="header-bg"></div>
    <div class="header-content">
      <ul>
        <li>YOUR HEADER</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
```

I made another [CodePen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/xZdZzz) for this.
The header-bg has a height of 0. The header-content has a height of, lets say, 80px, and a background-color of transparent. Now do NOT check which direction is scrolled. The only important aspect for the effect is, how far are you from the top / is a specific element in viewport? I went for `400px` from top. Now when that requirement is met, just fade in the header-bg. It will be inbetween the wrapper and the content, and will provide a background. Together with that, you may also change the color of the header-content, but I did not do that. It is what bartaile.com does, tho, so you might want to include it. Enjoy!

**Edit 2**: I've edited the CodePen according to your comment. See it in action [here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/xZdZzz). This does the following: A header is there. When scrolling down, it'll disappear. On scroll up, it'll bring up a background, but when scrolling so that scrollTop < 400, the background will fade out. As of what I understood, this is what you want. It uses the structure I posted above.

Comment: Is there not a more simple way to achieve this effect? http://bartaile.com is what I am using as inspiration and am simply adding: after the user scrolls past the first panel the nav hides unless the user scrolls up only then does it show again......I'll try your tips thank you for your help!

Comment: What bartaile.com is doing is a good idea, too. I will again create a CodePen and update you!

Comment: I apologize if I'm not understanding or being unclear. the only issue I'm coming across is the navigation transition on up scroll when panel 1 comes back down. I want the the navigation style to slide up rather then just drop off showing the white text & transparent background navigation style. I'm blending http://bartaile.com & http://charactersf.com if these examples help clarify any

Comment: I know that, but your current setup does not allow that. Take a look at my examples

Comment: Ok I think I understand the updated header example however I don't know how to make the nav hide after panel 1 and only show on up scroll. Also,I may be doing something really dumb here but,-- I'm trying to change the txt color after panel 1 from white to black however if I indicate a color for .header-content it will not transition and if I add classes in the jQuery it will load black and not white at first. https://jsfiddle.net/mdc5kv60/

Comment: I've added another update. Please tell me if this is what you want.

Answer (score 3):

I check out "bartaile.com" and I have to point out that what they use is a third party lib called 'fullpage'.If you wanna achieve that kind of effect, you should check out this lib [fullpage.js](http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/#firstPage). This is a simple and easy to use plugin to create fullscreen scrolling websites (also known as single page websites or onepage sites). It allows the creation of fullscreen scrolling websites, as well as adding some landscape sliders inside the sections of the site.

This plugin can handle "full screen scrolling" and also normal scrolling. You can achieve your effect with this much more easier